# Database Corruption on Active Directory ntds.dit file. Event 467 On Primary DC

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2016

I had some issues with my Primary Domain Controller last night. It blue screened and after restarting began a chkdsk. After some work, I was able to get the server back online and everything appears to be functional, but I am getting Event id 467 logs on it.

> NTDS (748) NTDSA: Database C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit: Index
>   DRA_USN_CRITICAL_index of table datatable is corrupted (0).

My other DC (I only have 2) does not display these logs and replication I believe is working.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Should I transfer roles to my secondary DC to make it my primary and then demote and promote the DC that is spitting out logs?

I also found this blog post about someone who had corruption on a secondary DC and was able to fix it: https://www.emmanuelrached.com/2014/11/20/dc-failing-due-to-corrupt-ntds-db/  It involves defragmenting the corrupted indexes and creating a new ntds.nit file. Is this something I should try?

I also have nightly full server backups that I can try to restore. Although I tried to do this last night and Windows Recovery couldn't find my .vhdx file even though I know it was there.

I'm really not sure what caused this. It is running on a VM and all hardware on the host looks good. No other VMs are having issues. I did recently install Microsoft Identity Management on it which I know is not recommended on a DC, but it shouldn't have caused this mess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such things as Primary of Secondary Domain Controllers. Those concepts died with Windows NT. All moderns DCs are multi-master peers.

Because of this, I wouldn't waste time trying to repair this specific error. I'd transfer the Operations Master roles, demote the failed DC, and remove it from the domain and spin up a fresh server to replace it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I guess I always thought of the DC with the master roles assigned to them still as "primary" DCs. That is what I was thinking, but was hoping there was an easier fix. I just thought of one more thing. I have nightly backups of this server and the log messages started only a couple of days ago. Could I try to restore the system state to resolve the issues?

Comment: @Intrepid I wouldn’t bother. It’s easier to just provision a new DC and then you know it’s clean.

Comment: getting an error when I try to transfer the PDC Role. If I try to transfer using powershell Move-ADDirectoryOperationMasterRole I get "Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole : The directory service is unavailable". If I try to move using the gui in AD Users and Computers I get "This computer is a non-replication partner. Do you want to continue with the transfer". Should I try to transfer the role using the Ntdsutil command?

Comment: This is what I got when trying to transfer with ntdsutil: fsmo maintenance: Transfer PDC
ldap_modify_sW error 0x34(52 (Unavailable).
Ldap extended error message is 000020AF: SvcErr: DSID-03210806, problem 5002 (UNAVAILABLE), data 8451

Win32 error returned is 0x20af(The requested FSMO operation failed. The current FSMO holder could not be contacted.)
)
Depending on the error code this may indicate a connection,
ldap, or role transfer error.      Should I attempt a forced transfer? All other roles transferred successfully.

Comment: @Intrepid sounds like you will have to seize the roles instead of transferring them.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's just the index, you can repair this by performing an offline defragmentation of the Active Directory database.

This will drop and recreate the index. Only cost me a 3 minute outage. Clone and test if you can.

https://asknicks.blogspot.com/2013/05/active-directory-database-corruption.html

See MS article [KB232122](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/232122/how-to-perform-offline-defragmentation-of-the-active-directory-databas)